# Why IndexOf not working with text 2 byte?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have this code as (`parm_strLineData` is a parameter of type `String`):

```
parm_strLineData = <Text>：<AK_F NO="1">7</AK_F>。ポジ</Text>

Dim iPosTagClose_Start As Integer = parm_strLineData.IndexOf("</AK",0)
```

Result: `iPosTagClose_Start = -1`

Note: character: 。 is 2byte

Why IndexOf not working with text 2 byte?

How fix?

Comment: Can you please write proper VB.NET code? If you convert the first line into proper VB.NET (code which compiles, including quote escaping), it would work fine.

Comment: and without `;` at the end

Comment: Sorry all value of parm_strLineData= <Text>：<AK_F NO="1">7</AK_F>゜ポジ</Text>

Comment: @user1497597: I cannot reproduce it. I get 21 as index. I have stored your string in a txt file encoded with unicode.

Comment: @ Dominic Kexel: Type of  parm_strLineData is String

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim parm_strLineData As String
parm_strLineData = <Text>:<AK_F NO="1">7</AK_F>???</Text>
```

Here you create a `XElement` and implicitly convert it to a string.

The result is that `parm_strLineData` now does *not* contain the *string* `<Text>:<AK_F NO="1">7</AK_F>???</Text>`, but [the concatenated string value of all of the element's text and descendant's text.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155263%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In your case, it's `：7゜ポジ`, and `：7゜ポジ` does not contain `"</AK"`, so the result of `IndexOf` is `-1`.

---

I don't know your real problem, but to solve this issue, use a `string` instead of an `XElement`:

```
parm_strLineData As String= "<Text>:<AK_F NO=""1"">7</AK_F>???</Text>"
```

If your goal is to check if an XML node exists, don't use string parsing, but e.g. Linq2Xml.

Comment: Does VB.NET implicitly convert XML to string?! Hideous.

Comment: @usr Only when using `Option Strict Off`. Every sane person should use `Option Strict On` where possible, since it disallows such implicit conversions.